# unix command './' is not recognized

Tags: matlab, unix, matlab-compiler

I'm using Matlab 2013a. The unix command './' doesn't work in matlab and returns the following error.

```
>> unix('./makeBeamxy.s')
'.' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there a way to solve it? I'm actually running this command from cygwin. But the 'system' command doesn't work very well because after I run this command, I need to keep the cgywin window open to run another command so that I can execute the file.

Comment: What is the result without `./`?

Comment: have you tried adding ! infront? It is the shell escape

Comment: Hi, NKN, the visual studio pops up and shows me the codes. I'm not sure if I should uninstall the visual studio.

Comment: Hi,  GameOfThrows, you mean unix('!./makeBeamxy.s') or !unix('./makeBeam.s')? Both don't work

Comment: I think `!./makeBeamxy.s` is what @GameOfThrows is referring to

Comment: Hi, Matt, none of them work unfortunately.

Comment: On my system (Linux R2015a) the error is `/bin/bash: ./makeBeamxy.s: No such file or directory`, which it should be since I don't have that (script?) file. It is very strange that Matlab thinks `.` is the command name.

Comment: if Windows was involved in creating or transporting (ftp, etc) your script file, then run `dos2unix /path/to/myMatLabScript` . Good luck.

Comment: do you have an incorrect space between `.` and `/makeBeamxy.s`?

Comment: Also check the mode of your file.

Comment: Hi Walter A, no incorrect space is in my code. I still don't know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
unix(fullfile('.','makeBeamxy.s'))
```